# Struggle when appending rows to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking forward to apply a function that involves 2 dfs:

```
df1:         A B C D E
   12/2/2001 3 4 2 3 4
   12/3/2001 5 5 5 4 6  
   12/4/2001 9 8 7 1 1

df_new = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df1)
df_new.loc[df_new.index[0]-pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)]=0
df_nuevo=df_new.sort_index()

for i in range(1,len(df_nuevo)):
    row=((df1.iloc[:i])*0.55)*((df_nuevo.iloc[:i-1])*0.45)
    df_nuevo.append(row)
print(df_nuevo)
```

The output I am expecting is `df_nuevo` filled with the appended rows. Actually gets filled by NaNs. Can anyone help ? Thank you .

This is the current output :

```
             A    B   C   D   E
   12/1/2001 0    0   0   0   0 
   12/2/2001 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   12/3/2001 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   12/4/2001 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

The idea is that where there are the NaNs appears the results of the formula specified in the part of the code : rows

Comment: hi, what is "tabla" ? "rdos1" ? what is the expected output?

Comment: Sorry, modified. The output is the new dataframe generated from applying the formula above in df:2 which I tried to generate looping rows

Comment: the t in the formula is not clear. Actually the piece of code is quite confusing ...Could you elaborate a little bit more the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to iteratively fill out rows of `df2` based on `df1` and prior values of `df2`, a simple recasting of your formula (at least the way you originally gave it in pseudo-code) would be:

```
# create all-zeros df2 same shape as df1
df2 = df1.copy()
df2.loc[:,:] = 0

# iteratively compute df2
for i in range(len(df1)):
    df2.iloc[i] = df1.iloc[i] * .55 + df2.iloc[i-1] * .45
```

For the given example above, the results for `df2` would be:

[image]

It may be instructive to see the values as they are updated through the loop:

```
i: 0
df1.iloc[i].values: array([ 3.,  4.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
df2.iloc[i - 1].values: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
resulting df2.iloc[i].values: array([ 1.65,  2.2 ,  1.1 ,  1.65,  2.2 ])

i: 1
df1.iloc[i].values: array([ 5.,  5.,  5.,  4.,  6.])
df2.iloc[i - 1].values: array([ 1.65,  2.2 ,  1.1 ,  1.65,  2.2 ])
resulting df2.iloc[i].values: array([ 3.4925,  3.74  ,  3.245 ,  2.9425,  4.29  ])

i: 2
df1.iloc[i].values: array([ 9.,  8.,  7.,  1.,  1.])
df2.iloc[i - 1].values: array([ 3.4925,  3.74  ,  3.245 ,  2.9425,  4.29  ])
resulting df2.iloc[i].values: array([ 6.521625,  6.083   ,  5.31025 ,  1.874125,  2.4805  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df1 = (df* 0.55 )+ (0.45 * df.shift())


                A       B       C       D       E
2001-12-02      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2001-12-03      4.1     4.55    3.65    3.55    5.10
2001-12-04      7.2     6.65    6.10    2.35    3.25
```

Comment: `(0.45 * df.shift())` should corrspond to the 2nd and empty dataframe , the resulting formula is `df2=(df1*0.55 + df2*0.45(in a previous period compared to df1))`this is what i am looking forward to loop. However I appreciate very much your help

Comment: @ge00rge, what is the desired output?

Comment: a new df defined in the code as `df_new` that fills in with the formula into each row. As soon as the first loop takes place, df2 will have its first row of values and will be as dealing with 2 normal dfs.

Comment: Its still not clear, whats the formula for rows of df1?

Comment: what about assuming that df2 has a previous period with 0s in relation to 
df1, makes it clear someway.

Comment: We are trying at the end to fill the rows of the empty df (df_2) with the given formula